# Vagrant virtual box returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from browser

Tags: vagrant

I'm very much a Vagrant noob so hope this is an easy issue to fix issue.

I've set up a Vagrant ubuntu/trusty64 box that aliases to an existing directory on my local machine that hosts the development files for a website. I gave the box an IP address (192.168.44.44) and set up domains in my 'hosts' file.

I can ssh into the box no problem and can navigate to the aliased files from within ssh. So the box is working as expected.

I can open a cmd window and ping both the IP address and domain without an issue.

But when I try to access the IP or the domain from within a browser I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. The error appears immediately without any delay.

I'm on a Windows 10 machine. Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the trusty64 box is just Linux but doesn't start with Apache. My other test environments when I looked at them were all LAMP boxes. So the reason all the various tests were working except for the browser was because Apache hadn't been installed.

I hope this helps someone if they have a similar issue.